# Using ffmpeg to extract images is very slow

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg on my Mac.
Version is 3.4.2.

I wanted images of a specific second of video and executed the following command.

```
ffmpeg -i sample.mkv -ss 100 -vframes 1 -f image2 %04d.png
```

This command took more than 1 minute to finish.
When I tried to take the image of the 1000th second, the response did not come back.

Is there something wrong with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use demuxer seek i.e. `-ss` before the input.

```
ffmpeg -ss 100 -i sample.mkv -vframes 1 -f image2 %04d.png
```